# Add TermSetGroup in Sharepoint via Code

Tags: c#, sharepoint, permissions

I've got a problem while creating a TermSetGroup. My code looks like this:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    //create new group if the groupName was not created.            
    Group group = termStore.Groups.Where(g => g.Name == groupName).Count() > 0 ? termStore.Groups[groupName] : termStore.CreateGroup(groupName);
    //create new term set if the termSetName was not created.
    TermSet termSet = group.TermSets.Where(s => s.Name == termSetName).Count() > 0 ? group.TermSets[termSetName] : group.CreateTermSet(termSetName);

    termSet.Owner = TermSetOwner;

    //add terms to term set.
    int lcid = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.LCID;
    foreach (string termName in terms)
    {
        if (termSet.GetTerms(termName, false).Count <= 0)
        {
            termSet.CreateTerm(termName, lcid);
        }
    }
    termStore.CommitAll();
});
```

This code actually works, if I use it in a separated console project. It creates my Group and in this Group also the TermSet. But when I use this code out of a webservice, which was called in a workflow, it tells me, that my user hasn't got the rights to create the group. 
When the group exists, it works, and it can create the TermSet.

How can this be, when I use "RunWithElevatedPrivileges"?
The user, who starts the workflow is the site admin. Even the Termstore Admin is the site admin...so what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is, what identity is your webservice running as? 
Because this is the identity that will be assumed. As long as you are running i a separate process than the IIS worker process (w3wp) using SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges will not grant you the system account identity.

Edit:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() { 
using(SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(YOUR_SITEID))
{
    var elevatedTSession = new TaxonomySession(SPContext.Current.Site);
    var elevatedTermstore = elevatedTSession.TermStores[0]; //Or other if you have more
    //your code here, but using elevatedTermstore instead
}
```

Comment: The webservice runs as the site admin and even if I do it with another administrator account, via a UserToken, it still doesnt work.

Comment: Maybe you need to get your reference to the termstore and the TaxonomySession from within the elevated clause? See my edited answer.

Comment: Hmm..really strange. I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.. :(

Comment: Hmm, well I have done it manually now. I will keep that question open though, maybe my co-worker can find a solution when he is back from his vacation...

Comment: Ok, I'm curious to find out what was wrong if you guys figure it out.